# Bitbucket Pipelines failing to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: bitbucket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket-pipelines

I have had pipelines working successfully for a while, but it seems to have stopped working on one of my branches (possibly more not tried yet).

The logs show:

```
Creating application version archive "app-f557-180519_203324".
Uploading: [--------------------------------------------------] 0% 
Uploading: [#########################-------------------------] 50% 
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% 
Done...
ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - No Application Version named 'app-f557-180519_203324' found.
```

If I deploy via my local command line it uploads fine and deploys fine, its only through pipelines.

It seems to be creating the version then uploading, but then can't seem to find its own version. Seems a bit odd, anyone know a solution?

Thanks

Kevin

Comment: I think this was to do with Amazon changing the be of one of the environments therefore what I had starting failing. I just rewrote the pipeline and it all worked again

Answer (score 0):

What version of aws tools is it running? I had the same problem on my local box, re-ran `eb init --interactive` and updated the tools to `EB CLI 3.14.1` and this error went away, deploying fine now.